# Create a lag vector with repeated entries

Tags: r, date, vector, lag

I would like to create a lagged vector, but the challenge is that some observations are repeated. Let's consider the following vector:

```
date <- c("2016-04-11", "2016-04-11", "2016-04-11", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2014-05-11")
```

The first three elements are observed at the same point in time (items of last order), the fourth and fifth (items of second last order) at the same time and the sixth at another time (first order, consisting only of one item).

The lagged vector should look like this:

```
date <- c("2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2014-05-11", "2014-05-11", NA)
```

Is there an easy way to create this lagged date vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run-length encode the data:

```
date <- c("2016-04-11", "2016-04-11", "2016-04-11", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-11", "2014-05-11")
res <- rle(date)
res$values <- c(res$values[-1], NA)
res <- inverse.rle(res)
#[1] "2015-05-11" "2015-05-11" "2015-05-11" "2014-05-11" "2014-05-11" NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks good. This was only a toy example, but in the "real" application the last entry might show up several times. Hence the handling with the "NA" should be vector-dependent as it does not always has to be exactly one value. In the real example the repitions pattern vary from observation to observation.

Comment: I don't understand your concern. If there was another `"2014-05-11"` in the input vector, the result would contain a second `NA`. You should check out what `rle` returns (i.e., study its documentation).